# write syscall gets considerably slower when called from another thread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, performance, linux-kernel

If you define `THR`, the code will do the same job but just in another thread. I only measured the time spent on the `write` call.

Running the code with `./some-file-name>/dev/null`, this is the result I get, which is the accumulated clock cycles.

`THR` not defined

```
   1    48930106
   2    43946464
   3    44669126
   4    45918011
   5    44108477
   6    43608789
   7    45104427
   8    49676889
   9    44682305
  10    47516931
```

`THR` defined

```
   1   108347418
   2   101670307
   3   101726085
   4   100531554
   5   100137343
   6    85837022
   7   105556754
   8   104681843
   9   110303338
  10   104666783
```

Why is `write` when called from another thread so much slower?

The system is Fedora Linux.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <atomic>
using namespace std;
#else
#include <stdatomic.h>
#endif

#define SIZE 0x100000

static unsigned long long rdtscp() {
    unsigned _;
    return __rdtscp(&_);
}

static char b[SIZE];
static atomic_ullong oc;
#ifdef THR
static sem_t s[2];

void *out(void *_) {
    for (;;) {
        sem_wait(s);
        unsigned long long c = rdtscp();
        write(1, b, SIZE);
        oc += rdtscp() - c;
        sem_post(s + 1);
    }
    return _;
}
#endif

int main() {
    memset(b, 'a', SIZE);
#ifdef THR
    sem_init(s, false, 0);
    sem_init(s + 1, false, 0);
    pthread_t t;
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, out, NULL);
#endif
    for (int i = 1;; ++i) {
    #ifdef THR
        sem_post(s);
        sem_wait(s + 1);
    #else
        unsigned long long c = rdtscp();
        write(1, b, SIZE);
        oc += rdtscp() - c;
    #endif
        const int d = 100000;
        if (!(i % d)) {
            unsigned long long _oc = atomic_exchange(&oc, 0);
            fprintf(stderr, "%4d%12llu\n", i / d, _oc);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Not sure if this is okay, but I made the code both compile in C and C++ to add the C++ tag. I will roll back if this is inappropriate.

Comment: My guess would be some cpu cache invalidation due to synchronization.

Comment: What is your cpu? Try disabling frequency scaling and turbo boost.

Comment: From [Wikipedia - Time Stamp Counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) >The Time Stamp Counter was once an excellent high-resolution, low-overhead way for a program to get CPU timing information. With the advent of multi-core/hyper-threaded CPUs, systems with multiple CPUs, and hibernating operating systems, the TSC cannot be relied upon to provide accurate results — unless great care is taken to correct the possible flaws: ...

Comment: @OlafDietsche This might be even more relevant from the Wikipedia entry:  "There is no promise that the timestamp counters of multiple CPUs on a single motherboard will be synchronized."

Comment: @Angelom, the sem* functions are system calls. It's no surprise this is slower, the code is adding more locking, this is expected.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Though no promise, they are on pretty much all modern systems.

Comment: @OlafDietsche That's why I used `rdtscp` instead of `rdtsc`. It does insure that `all previous instructions have executed and all previous loads are globally visible` according to the manual.

Comment: @AndrewHenle See my above comment, and also, a lot of modern x86_64 CPUs have a guarantee that the time stamp counters will have a consistent tick. You can check this by `TscInvariant` from `CPUID`.

Comment: You could account for the overhead of the `sem_post` and `sem_wait` calls by adding a dummy semaphore to the non-THR variant as well.

Answer (score 0):

In one case, the data to be written is hot in the core's cache. There's no synchronization or dispatch overhead.

In the other case, the data to be written is modified in some other core's cache. There's both synchronization and dispatch overhead.

It's not surprising it takes more clock cycle to process the data when caches are cold, cores have to be synchronized, and a new task has to be dispatched rather than an existing task simply continuing.

A common anti-pattern is to convey data from thread to thread rather than processing it to completion in a single thread.

Comment: The data to be written is not modified after the initial `memset`. The only synchronization required is the internal data of the `semaphore`. But since there is a slowdown, can I guess that synchronizing and dispatching a small amount of data stored in cache cause the whole cache to become "cold", having to reload also the unmodified data again?

Comment: @xiver77 The thread that calls `memset` will have the data to be written modified in its cache. When `write` is called by another thread which accesses the data, cache coherency operations are required to synchronize the caches. It doesn't have to be loaded *again*, it has to be loaded for the first time in the other core. This is why conveying data from thread to thread is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Then how does a one-time synchronization cause a big slowdown across multiple same operations?

Comment: @xiver77 It doesn't, and I didn't say it did. It's just one of the reasons the threaded code is slower. Notice the single-threaded code didn't have quite as huge a penalty on the first iteration?

Comment: It would be better not to guess, but to measure with perf.